# Wildcards in Generics: "? super T" works while "? extends T" does not?

Tags: java, generics, java-7

My question is about generics in Java 7. Suppose we have such class hierarchy:

```
interface Animal {}    
class Lion implements Animal {}    
class Butterfly implements Animal {}
```

Just like in [Java Generics Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Also we have a class

```
class Cage<T> {
    private List<T> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    public void add(T t) {
        arr.add(t);
    }
    public T get() {
        return arr.get(0);
    }
}
```

And here is the code which uses that classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cage<? extends Animal> cage = new Cage<>();
        Animal a = cage.get(); //OK
        cage.add(new Lion()); //Compile-time error
        cage.add(new Butterfly()); //Compile-time error   
    }
```

Question #1:

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/generics-in-java-using-wildcards#answer-503765) about these issues but there was simply like `Cage<?>`. But I tell the compiler `<? extends Animal>` so type `T` in `Cage<T>` will be any of subtypes of Animal type. So why it still gives a compile time error?

Question #2:

If I specify `Cage<? super Animal> cage = ...` instead of `Cage<? extends Animal> cage = ...` everything works fine and compiler doesn't say anything bad. Why in this case it works fine while in the example above it fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cage must be able to hold *both* types of animals.  "super" says that - it says that the Cage must be able to hold *all* types of animals - and maybe some other things, too, because `? super Animal` might be a superclass of Animal.  "extends" says that it can hold *some* kinds of animals - maybe just Lions, for instance, as in:

```
Cage<? extends Animal> cage = new Cage<Lion>();
```

which would be a valid statement, but obviously the lion cage won't hold butterflies, so

```
cage.add(new Butterfly());
```

wouldn't compile.  The statement

```
cage.add(new Lion());
```

wouldn't compile either, because Java here is looking at the declaration of the cage - `Cage<? extends Animal>` - not the object that's assigned to it right now (`Cage<Lion>`).

The best description of generics I know of is in [O'Reilly's Java in a Nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007736).  The chapter is free online - [part 1](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/) and [part 2](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/index1.html).

Comment: and cage.add(new Lion()) wouldn't compile too.

Comment: According to the java tutorial "super" says thay it can hold all types which are supertypes for Animal: "The code <? super Animal>, therefore, would be read as "an unknown type that is a supertype of Animal, possibly Animal itself"". But neither Lion nor Butterfly aren't super types for Animal, why it works?

Comment: Think of `<? super Animal>` as controlling what kinds of _classes_ would be allowed to be _assigned_ to variable "cage" - not what kinds of objects can be _held_ by the cage.  So here it means the Cage has to be a Cage<Animal or a superclass> - which means that it can handle all animals.  Does that help?  This _is_ confusing!