# Generic lower unbound vs upper bounded wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

interface Canine {}
class Dog implements Canine {}
public class Collie extends Dog {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Dog> d = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        List<Collie> c = new ArrayList<Collie>();
        d.add(new Collie());
        c.add(new Collie());
        do1(d); do1(c);
        do2(d); do2(c);
    }
    static void do1(List<? extends Dog> d2){
        d2.add(new Collie());
        System.out.print(d2.size());
    }
    static void do2(List<? super Collie> c2){
        c2.add(new Collie());
        System.out.print(c2.size());
    }
}
```

The answer for this question tell that when a method takes a wildcard generic typ, the collection can be accessed or modified, but not both. (Kathy and Bert)

**What does it mean '*when a method takes a wildcard generic typ, the collection can be accessed or modified, but not both*' ?**

As far as I know,
The method do1 has `List<? extends Dog> d2` so d2 only can be accessed but not modified.
The method d2 has `List<? super Collie> c2` so c2 can be accessed and modified and there is no compilation error.

[Generic guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html)

Comment: See [what is the difference between 'super' and 'extends' in Java Generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910892/what-is-the-difference-between-super-and-extends-in-java-generics)

Comment: See [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: See [Wildcards in Generics: “? super T” works while “? extends T” does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541849/wildcards-in-generics-super-t-works-while-extends-t-does-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer for this question tell that when a method takes a wildcard generic typ, the collection can be accessed or modified, but not both. (Kathy and Bert)

That's a fair first approximation, but not quite correct. More correct would be:

You can only add null to a `Collection<? extends Dog>` because its add method takes an argument of `? extends Dog`. Whenever you invoke a method, you must pass parameters that are of a subtype of the declared parameter type; but for the parameter type `? extends Dog`, the compiler can only be sure that the argument is of compatible type if the expression is `null`. However, you can of course modify the collection by calling `clear()` or `remove(Object)`.

On the other hand, if you read from a `Collection<? super Dog>`, its iterator has return type `? super Dog`. That is, it will return objects that are a subtype of some unknown supertype of `Dog`. But differently, the Collection could be a `Collection<Object>` containing only instances of `String`. Therefore

```
for (Dog d : collection) { ... } // does not compile
```

so the only thing we know is that instances of Object are returned, i.e. the only type-correct way of iterating such a Collection is

```
for (Object o : collection) { ... }
```

but it is possible to read from a collection, you just don't know what types of objects you will get.

We can easily generalize that observation to: Given

```
class G<T> { ... }
```

and

```
G<? extends Something> g;
```

we can only pass null to method parameters with declared type `T`, but we can invoke methods with return type `T`, and assign the result a variable of type `Something`.

On the other hand, for

```
G<? super Something> g;
```

we can pass any expression of type `Something` to method parameters with declared type `T`, and we can invoke methods with return type `T`, but only assign the result to a variable of type `Object`.

To summarize, the restrictions on the use of wildcard types only depend on the form of the method declarations, not on what the methods do.

Comment: Yes, null, it can be assigned to any reference of any type, which includes all types that extend Dog

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a `Cat` to a `List<? extends Animal>` because you don't know what kind of list that is. That could be a `List<Dog>` also. So you don't want to throw your `Cat` into a `Black Hole`. That is why `modification` of `List` declared that way is not allowed.

Similarly when you fetch something out of a `List<? super Animal>`, you don't know what you will get out of it. You can even get an `Object`, or an `Animal`. But, you can add an `Animal` safely in this `List`.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code into my IDE. The following error was signalled inside `do1`:

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Dog) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Collie)

This is, of course, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot add a `Collie` to a `List<? extends Dog>` because this reference may hold for example a `List<Spaniel>`.

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into IDEONE http://ideone.com/msMcQ.  It did not compile for me - which is what I expected.  Are you sure you did not have any compilation errors?

Comment: I know that there is a compiler error in do1 method when it try to add an element. My doubt is about what Katy & Bert say.
'when a method takes a wildcard generic typ, the collection can be accessed or modified, but not both'
And with <? super Collie> I can access and add elements.¿?

Comment: @Joe.  OK I misunderstood your question and thought you were implying that your code compiled.  Now, you are not accessing elements in method `do2`.  The `c2.size()` does not count as an access.  An access would be something like `Collie c = c2 . get ( 0 ) ;`  I revised my example http://ideone.com/msMcQ with code that illustrates