# Is there a need to use bounded wildcard generics in a passthrough method?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I know that in the following method in `Collection<E>`:

```
public void addAll(Collection<? extends E> subcollection);
```

We use `Collection<? super E>` there to allow a collection that solely exists of sub-elements, example:

```
List<Drivable> drivables = new ArrayList<>();
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
//we need the wildcard here, because of the following line:
drivables.addAll(cars);
```

However, are such bounded wildcards needed in my following method?

```
public static <E> Collection<E> requireNonEmpty(final Collection<E> collection) throws NoSuchElementException {
    if (collection.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("collection must be non-empty");
    }
    return collection;
}
```

This uses a similar idiom as `Objects.requireNonNull(T object)`, which actually returns the `T object`.

So, is there any benefit (or is it even wrong?) to write my method as the following?

```
public static <E> Collection<? super E> 
    requireNonEmpty(final Collection<? extends E> collection);
```

Comment: You might want to read this - [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/738746).

Comment: @BheshGurung I have read that, however I seem to not be able to apply that information on my usecase here.

Comment: You method itself is generic, so you could pass collection of any type to it. Imagine if the type parameter `E` was declared at the class level and your method as an instance method, and you wanted to method to take a collection of E or any subclass/superclass of E then you would need to use it.

Comment: For whatever you are doing in your method, I don't see why you would want to use bounds.

Comment: Note that the `requireNonEmpty` return type is losing information, unlike `requireNonNull`. For example, one could pass in a `Set<String>` and only get a `Collection<String>` back. To remedy this, it should be declared as `public static <C extends Collection<?>> C requireNonEmpty(final C collection)`.

Comment: Paul Bellora should extend that comment into an answer, because it is correct. On such a function, there is no need to lose type information.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Collection<? extends E> subcollection` makes the passed parameter a *universal donor* - i.e. it can be read from with freedom.

You do not need to read objects from the passed collection so you do not need any wildcards.

Incidentally using `Collection<? super E> subcollection` makes it a universal recipient - i.e. you can add to it.

See [When to use extends and super](http://onewebsql.com/blog/generics-extends-super) for a clear introduction.

Also a good answer covering this [Generic lower unbound vs upper bounded wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12895033/823393).