# Use a class inside a LinkedHashMap accepting its subclass as value

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

Sorry if it's a silly question, but I have searched a long time and couldn't understand why the code below throws me a compilation error:

I have a first class named MenuElement which is parent to a few subclasses. It has 2 methods:

```
class MenuElement {
   public int getType() {};
   public long getId() {};
   ... 
}
```

In another class, I have declared as attribute:

```
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap <Long, ? extends MenuElement>> mMenuElement;
```

And in one of the method, I have this, but the compiler cannot accept menuElement as a chidren of MenuElement:

```
public void onMenuElementActivationChanged(MenuElement menuElement) {
...
    mMenuElement.get(menuElement.getType()).put(menuElement.getId(), menuElement);
...
}
```

I feel like I'm maybe missing something with java's generics logic. Someone can help please? 
Thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you use just private LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap <Long, MenuElement>> mMenuElement;

Comment: @Kai-Xin Please write the exact compiler error

Comment: @uoyilmaz
Actually, in the constructor, mMenuElement is initialized with a LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Long, ? extends MenuElement>>

Comment: That's the problem, initialize it as private LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap <Long, MenuElement>> mMenuElement;

Comment: @Eduardo Yáñez Parareda

Error:(737, 32) error: constructor MenuElementsView in class MenuElementsView cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,Dish,LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Long,? extends MenuElement>>,int,boolean,DishDetailsMenuElementViewCallbacks
found: Activity,Dish,LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<? extends MenuElement>>,int,boolean,MainActivity
reason: actual argument LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<? extends MenuElement>> cannot be converted to LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Long,? extends MenuElement>> by method invocation conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake in generics.

The parameter list of a generic must **match exactly** for it to compile. Thus `<? extends X>` will **not** match `X` because `X` does not `extend` `X`. The following works fine.

```
abstract class MenuElement {

    public abstract int getType();

    public abstract long getId();
}

public void test() {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap <Long, MenuElement>> mMenuElement = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    MenuElement me;
    mMenuElement.get(me.getType()).put(me.getId(), me);
```

It is **very** unusual to need to use `<? ...>` in generics. In most cases the real type is fine. Normal rules apply for generics type matching anyway - i.e. an object of type `B extends A` or `B implements A` can still be used when the generic is defined as accepting an `A`.

For example:

```
private static class X {

    public X() {
    }
}

private static class Y {

    public Y() {
    }
}

private static class Z extends Y {

    public Z() {
    }
}

public void test() {
    Map<X, Y> map = new HashMap<>();
    // Both of these work fine.
    map.put(new X(), new Y());
    map.put(new X(), new Z());
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was wondering why it didn't compile while in my logics, a subclass of MenuElement _is_ a MenuElement... But I guess then what I wanted to do is then just impossible. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: @KaiXin - No - my point is that in most cases what you want to do can be done **without** `?`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23199614/823393) to a simialr question for some useful links.

Answer (score 0):

The way you specify your map, it simply cannot be added to at all.

Basically, your `put` method is declared as

```
put(Object key, ? extends MenuElement value)
```

`? extends MenuElement` in this case means "some unknow type derived from MenuElement". Not "any type derived from MenuElement": some specific, but unknown type. Thus, you cannot pass any instance of a particular class as second argument of `put`: none of them belong to that "unknown" type.

That's one of the limitations of wildcards in Java: `? extends` makes it impossible to pass data in, but OK to get data out, and `? super` makes it impossible to get data out, but possible to pass the data in.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have posted indicates you are using ArrayList instead of LinkedHashMap. The definition expects the Outer Map to have Integer->LinkedHashMap. Please check the code where you are constructing an instance of mMenuElement, and see if you can replace that ArrayList with a Map.

```
reason: actual argument LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<? extends MenuElement>> cannot be converted to LinkedHashMap<Integer,LinkedHashMap<Long,? extends MenuElement>> by method
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when copy/pasting from Android studio. Thanks for your help.