# Java unbound wildcard generics

Tags: java, generics, nested, bounded-wildcard

Are there any advantages of using wildcard-type generics in the `Bar` class over completely skipping them?

```
public class Foo<T> {}

public interface Bar {
    public void addFoo(Foo<?> foo);
    public Foo<?> getFoo(String name);
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503721/generics-in-java-using-wildcards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple advantages.

- They won't produce compiler warnings like using the raw type would
- They give more type safety.  For example, consider if `Foo` was `List` instead.  If you used `List` instead of `List<?>`, you could do this:

  ```
  myBar.getFoo("numbers").add("some string");
  ```

  even if the list was only *supposed* to contain `Number`s.  If you returned a `List<?>`, then you would not be able to add *anything* to it (except `null`) since the type of list is not known.
- They document something completely different than a raw type, namely that `Foo` is typed on some *unknown but specific type*.