# Java generics, Unbound wildcards <?> vs <Object>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I've read a few topics which cover certain questions about generics, such as their [relationship with raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164886/java-unbound-wildcard-generics). But I'd like an additional explanation on a certain line found in the  [Java SE tutorial on unbound generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) .

According to a sentence :

> The goal of printList is to print a list of any type, but it fails to achieve that goal — it prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print List<Integer>, List<String>, List<Double>, and so on, because they are not subtypes of List<Object>.

If I understand well this sentence; the difference between `List<?>` and `List<Object>`, is that we can use the type argument `List<String>` or `List<Integer>` by implementing the former. While if we implement the later, we can only use the type argument `List<Object>`. As if `List<?>` is an upper bound to `Object` namely `List<? extends Object>`.

But then the following sentence confuses me, in the sense that according to what I previously understood, `List<Object>` should only contain instances of the class `Object` and not something else.

> It's important to note that `List<Object>` and `List<?>` are not the same. You can insert an Object, or any subtype of Object, into a `List<Object>`. But you can only insert `null` into a `List<?>`.

Comment: I've got to go with "unclear what you're asking" here.

Comment: He wants `an additional explanation`.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting your info from, but both of those example sentences you provide are wrong.

Comment: @jervine10, check the link, it's the java se tutorial in oracle.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are two separate issues here. A `List<Object>` can in fact take any object as you say. A `List<Number>` can take *at least* `Number` objects, or of course any subclasses, like `Integer`.

However a method like this:

```java
public void print(List<Number> list);
```

will actually **only** take a `List` which is **exactly** `List<Number>`. It will not take any list which is declared `List<Integer>`.

So the difference is `List<?>` will take any List with whatever declaration, but `List<Object>` will **only** take something that was *declared* as `List<Object>`, nothing else.

The last quote simply states, that `List<?>` is a list for which you literally don't know what type its items are. Because of that, you can not add anything to it other than `null`.

Comment: And how about `List<? extends Number>`?

Comment: `List<? extends Number>` would take any list that is *declared* to at least Number, so it would take `List<Number>` and `List<Integer>`

Comment: That may be worth a mention, given that `List<?>` is somewhat analogous to `List<? extends Object>`. So the difference between `List<Object>` and `List<?>` is like the difference between `List<Number>` and `List<? extends Number>`.

Comment: Is the assumption I made here correct?

`As if List<?> is an upper bound to Object namely List<? Object>.`

Comment: *"Because of that, you can not do anything with it, other than to add `null`."* I guess you mean "you can not add anything to it, ...", because you can still perform other list operations on it.

Comment: `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>` are idencial, not only "_somewhat analogous_". Its simply a shortcut. [Difference ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055389/whats-the-difference-between-and-extends-object-in-java-generics), [Nam Ha Minh](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/generics-with-extends-and-super-wildcards-and-the-get-and-put-principle)

Comment: The one exception is that any `<? extends ...>` type is seen as nonreifiable, while `t instanceof Interface<?>` is allowed.

Comment: Then what's the difference between `List` and `List<?>` ?

Comment: @ParsaNoori `List` with a missing generic parameter will mean `List<Object>`, for backward compatibility reasons. So, the same difference as `List<Object>` vs. `List<?>`.

Answer (score 22):

The sentence that is confusing you is trying to warn you that, while `List<?>` is the super-type of all generic lists, you cannot add anything to a `List<?>` collection.

Suppose you tried the following code:

```
private static void addObjectToList1(final List<?> aList, final Object o ) {
    aList.add(o);
}

private static void addObjectToList2(final List<Object> aList, final Object o ) {
    aList.add(o);
}

private static <T> void addObjectToList3(final List<T> aList, final T o ) {
    aList.add(o);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "Add me!";
    addObjectToList1(testList, s);
    addObjectToList2(testList, s);
    addObjectToList3(testList, s);
}
```

`addObjectToList1` doesn't compile, because you cannot add anything except `null` to a `List<?>`.  (That's what the sentence is trying to tell you.)

`addObjectToList2` compiles, but the call to it in `main()` doesn't compile, because `List<Object>` is not a super type of `List<String>`.

`addObjectToList3` both compiles and the call works.  This is the way to add elements to a generic list.